# goodness of fit for psychometric data (perceptual threshold)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, goodness-of-fit, threshold, psychology, audio

I'm running an experiment on perceptual thresholds in audio. I'll try not to bog you down with too many details:

The experiment is about vibrato speed; specifically, when can you tell the difference between two stimuli that differ in *vibrato speed* only. Our software determines subjects' 50% threshold as a function of speed-difference; i.e., the difference in vibrato that is imperceivable.

It is run in 5 conditions, based on 5 "base vibrato speeds" (without getting into technical language, basically: slow, medium, fast (and steps in between)).

So, in the end our data look like this:

- Independent variable: "base vibrato speed" (slow, med, fast).
- Dependent variable: largest imperceivable difference in vibrato speed (the 50% threshold as determined by the software/experiment).

We hypothesize that as the base vibrato speed gets higher, the dependent variable (perceivable speed-difference) grows exponentially. Linear would be the null hypothesis.

So I'd like to fit both a linear regression, and some kind of exponential function to the data, and calculate a goodness of fit on both. Somehow I'm thinking chi-square won't cut the mustard here.

Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Why linear as null hypothesis, and not "no difference"? Or do you mean by linear, constant in relative terms? (+s% just noticable, regardless of base speed)? In either case I would first do a statistical test against the null, before testing alternate hypothesis

Comment: Good idea. What would be the best test for "no difference"?